# jssor slider thumbnail scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, jssor

I'm using jssor Slider with Thumbnail Navigator and I'm putting the Gallery inside Bootstrap modal window.
I'm trying to add scrollbar to the Thumbnail Navigator.
I can't seem to find the option to enable scrollbar so I'm adding a hack to allow scrollbar.

The code is:

```
$('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("div#gallery_list_slide:nth-child(2)").css("overflow-y","hidden");
    $("div#gallery_list_slide:nth-child(2)").css("width","265px");
});

$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e) {
    $("div#gallery_list_slide:nth-child(2)").css("overflow-y","scroll");
    $("div#gallery_list_slide:nth-child(2)").css("width","290px");
});
```

'#myModal' is the id for modal window
'#gallery_list_slide' is id for

The scrollbar seems to be working fine in Chrome but the problem is with Firefox.
In Firefox, when I click the scrollbar and scroll down, the last 2 thumbnails will cover the other thumbnails.

You can check the slider from this link:
[jssor gallery](http://www.kotaminyak.com/)

Since I'm new with jquery and js, I don't know how to properly add the scrollbar.
I would really appreciate any help
Thank you

Comment: why not use jssor slider native thumbnail navigator?

Comment: Yes, I'm using the native thumbnail navigator. I'm using the image-gallery-with-vertical-thumbnail.source sample. The problem is that I need to add vertical scrollbar at the thumbnail navigator

Comment: I see. I don't know how to get a scrollbar on thumbnail navigator work at the moment.

Comment: I see. I actually managed to show the scrollbar, but in Firefox it's behaving weirdly. Since I'm not very good with JS, I can't quite figure out what cause it. I would really appreciate if you can help me out. Thanks

Comment: I am very sorry that I still can't figure it out.

Comment: No worries. Can you let me know if there's a way to disable the drag in thumbnail navigator?

Comment: Please set $DragOrientation to 0 for $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions